# перестали обрабатываться запросы по API

Tags: android

[image: трассировка]прошу помощи:
Перестали обрабатываться запросы по API к базе данных с фильмами.
(Ключ к API рабочий, техподдержка сайта и провайдера ответили что у них всё хорошо).

При трассировке выяснил, что пакет от меня идёт на сайт и дальше не идёт.
Браузер выдаёт сообщение о том, что этот сайт с вредоносным ПО.
Прошу ответить на вопросы:

1. если это действительно вредоносный сайт, то как задать безопасный маршрут для передачи пакета?